# Super low fps when I import my own exported obj or fbx file

Tags: .fbx, timeline, obj

I have made my own head with hair in blender. But when I export it to fbx or obj the file is super slow and I cannot do anything... The fps is below 1 when I want to play the timeline. Is there something I can do about this?

Comment: This might be due to high poly counts.

Comment: Is there something I can do about that?